# Defining format globally for an environment

Tags: fonts, environments, newspaper

I am using `newspaper` package. It has an environment `\headline`. To change the format of `\headline`, I have to use `\headline{\it \huge Some Headline }`. I wonder how can I redefine `\headline` to have the same format for whole document. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a  *command*, not an environment. As this command has a short definition, the simplest thing to do is to re-define it in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\headline[1]{%
  \begin{center}\itshape\huge
  #1\\
  \rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}
  \end{center}
}%
```

Please do not use the deprecated (for more than 20 years!) font commands such as `\it`, `\bf`, &c.  Use the `nfss` commands or switches `\textit{…}` or `\itshape`, `\textbf{…}`or `\bfseries`, and so on.

Comment: oh... you were faster! : )

Comment: I removed the `\par` after `\end{center}` which does nothing.

Comment: @egreg: I must say I didn't test the code to understand why this final `\par`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. If I use `\renewcommand\headline[1]{\itshape   \huge   #1 }`, it changes the formatting of all following text. Would appreciate if you guide me how to force this formatting for only `headline`. Thanks

Comment: Could you post a minimal exemple showing the problem, that I can play with? But maybe, first try writing `{\texit{\huge #1}}`.

Comment: If I understand well, you removed the `center` environment?

Comment: Yes, I want to text left aligned with justification and underline. Any help, please.

Comment: Underline? It can be done, but it will be ugly and bring us back to the ancient times of typewriters…

Comment: That said, will the text inside be normal text?

Answer (score 4):

`\headline` is defined like this:

```
\newcommand\headline[1]{\begin{center} #1\\ %
\rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
```

you could use `\renewcommand*` to set a new general format for the document, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand*\headline[1]{\begin{center}\itshape \huge #1\\ %
\rule[3pt]{0.4\hsize}{0.5pt}\\ \end{center} \par}
```

This way your customizations are added to default `\headline` style. You could even rewrite the macro from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. If I use `\renewcommand\headline[1]{\itshape   \huge   #1 }`, it changes the formatting of all following text. Would appreciate if you guide me how to force this formatting for only `headline`. Thanks

Comment: you need to enclose the `\itshape` scope into a group: `\headline[1]{{\itshape \huge #1 }}` (notice the additional pair of `{}`)